# Dynamic dbrekalo fastselect with Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to find a way to populate my multiple select(fastselect) dropdown from one of my controllers. I tried to put an ajax request by binding a click event to the multiple select. The `data-url` attribute of multiple select will then be equal to ajax's response which is encoded in json. I thought this will be possible since in the dbrekalo fastselect's documentation, the `data-url` attribute accepts json file(so I thought it can accept any parameters/value as a long as it returns json).

I also tried to create a dummy json file, saved in my views folder and put the file name in `data-url` attribute but I get the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '16894' in <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Please tell me how can I successfully achieve this. I cannot find an alternative jquery plugin for multiple selection that can add others(not availabe in the current list) feature.

This is how the view looks like:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
<input
    id="multip"
    type="text"
    multiple
    class="multipleSelect"
    data-user-option-allowed="true"
    data-load-once="false"
    name="skills[]";/>
</div>
```

The ajax:

```
$(".multipleSelect").click(function() {

        var url = "<?php echo base_url()?>applicant/get_skill_list";
        $.ajax({

            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#multip").attr("data-url", data);
            }
        });
    });
```

My controller:

```
 public function get_skill_list() {

        $data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_skill_list();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your `json response`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no response. I was thinking that my ajax is not triggering. Thank you for your response @ShyamShingadiya

Comment: Okay, In your controller function you need to add `echo json_encode($data);`, If you share controller function code than we can help you better.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya Yes, I have that statement at the end of my controller function. I already add my controller function in my post.

Answer (score 0):

In fastselect plugin data will be loaded through ajax dynamically, In this case you need to use below lines.

```
<input type="text" id="multip" class="singleInputDynamic" data-url="<?php echo base_url('applicant/get_skill_list')?>" data-load-once="true" name="language" />


<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#multip').fastselect();
</script>
```

With this make sure your data is coming in below format. `text-value` pair.

```
[
    {"text": "Afghanistan", "value": "Afghanistan"},
    {"text": "Albania", "value": "Albania"},
    {"text": "Algeria", "value": "Algeria"},
    {"text": "Angola", "value": "Angola"}
]
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is still not working. I tried to remove some attributes of my input tag (attributes that fastselect provides). I left just the id and type attribute and the ajax is successfully working. So I think the problem might be on the fastselect plugin.

Comment: Please check my updated solution this will help you.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I also tried to do that but it still won't work. That's why I asked if the `data-url` must only accept a json file.

Comment: Also please make sure your response will be in text-value pair. Like in my answer.